# how to check heteroskedasticity in pyhton?

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, heteroscedasticity, statsmodels

After building model by using glm. How to check heteroskedasticity? are there any tests available to find or is it checked by using graphs??

Comment: Check this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/heteroscedasticity-is-nothing-to-be-afraid-of-730dd3f7ca1f